# Am I approaching making a "friend" collection the correct way?

Tags: meteor

I want to have the ability in my application for a user to befriend another user. A friend request is sent, and then the other person has the option to accept or not. I want there to be two different lists, the first list being the users friends, and the second being people who sent friend requests to him or her. Currently I have a friend collection:

```
Friends = new Meteor.Collection("friends");
```

The way I am creating friends is:

```
Template.friend.events({
    'click #addFriend': function(e, t) {
        var email = $("#friendEmail").val();
        var friend = Meteor.users.find({ "email.address" : email });
        if (friend) {
             return Friends.insert({friend1:Meteor.userId(),
                                    friend2:friend._id,
                                    name: email,
                                    stat: 'Pending'});
        }
    }
});
```

Now I get a little stuck, I have a template at the moment to retrieve friends:

```
Template.friend.friends = function () {
    return Friends.find({friend1: Meteor.userId()});
}
```

And then I have in my html:

```
{{#each friends}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="... columns">
      <p>{{name}} {{stat}}</p>
    <div class="... columns">
      <p>{{name}} {{stat}}</p>
    </div>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

to render the friends.

But here is the problem: How do I make sure friend two can accept any requests, and how do I make two separate columns? More importantly, I feel this is an incorrect way of doing things, should I even be approaching it this way?

EDIT:

I have gotten rid of the `Friends` collection and made a `Notifications` collection following phoenix's protocols, and I have created the following to test and see if it would work:

```
Template.friends.sent = function() {
    return Notifications.find({from: Meteor.user(),
                               type: "friendship"
                              });
}
```

With the following html:

```
{#each sent}
  <p>{{to.emails.0.address}}</p>
{/each}
```

But it returns an error saying:

```
Expected IDENTIFIER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep two collections:

`Meteor.users` and `Notifications`

When a friend request is sent you register it on `Notifications`, with `type : friendship`, `status : pending`, `from : user1` and `to : user2`.

Then, say in the user profile, you can query for the pending notifications that user2 regardless of from whom they are. If user2 accepts then you register it for user1 on collection `Meteor.users`. After the request is processed, either if accepted or not, you can delete the notification.

In fact, I you could even take out the property `status` from the collection `Notificationts` since in this approach you can end up deleting them anyway.

Regarding the two column template. Are you using Bootstrap or plain css?

With Bootstrap (3 in this case):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">{{columnOne}}</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">{{columnTwo}}</div>
</div>
```

With plain CSS

```
.row { width: 100%; }
.column { width: 50% }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, I updated my question, if you don't know how to answer the second part, I am considering splitting this up into two questions. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Hey Anon! Glad my answer was of some use. I think I would be better to make a github repository all together for this so we can hack on it. Talk you later!

Comment: I have a github repository. Currently it is private since it doesn't really do anything at the momment and I don't want to make it public till it actually works, but I can add you as a github collaborator if I can have your github user name. :D I'll get to drafting the goals of the project when I can but I have a lot of studying .

Comment: Of course! I just created an account, `stringparser`.

Comment: Ok, I have added you. You can run the project with `mrt` (meteor by itself doesn't have some of the libraries I use).

Comment: In your repo is, on a new branch. Is not finished though. Maybe next week. See ya.