# Retrieve user email given userId

Tags: meteor

This is more or less a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351391/am-i-approaching-making-a-friend-collection-the-correct-way).

I am trying to display "friends", I have a list of friends I sent a request to (called sent):

```
{{#each sent}}
  <p>{{find_user _id}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Sent is generated like so:

```
Template.friends.sent = function () {
    return Notifications.find({from: Meteor.userId(),  // to, and from are now userIds and not the user like in the original question.
                               type: 'friendship'});
}
```

And a query for the count gives a number of seven. My find_user template is defined as such:

```
Template.friends.find_user = function (id) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: id});
}
```

How can I get the email from the a user id? Doing something like:

```
{{(find_user _id).emails.[0].address}}
```

fails, with:

```
Expected IDENTIFIER.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first it appears you are iterating over a cursor from a Notifications collection and then calling the find_user method on the template with the _id of a Notification record. You'll need to use the from field of the document as it's the field that contains the userId.

Next you'll want to at least rewrite your find_user method so that it doesn't take a parameter. You can access the same data from within the helper because `this` is set to the current data context.

```
Template.friends.find_user = function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.from}); //note the this.from
}
```

Then you should be able to access the email address with via your template helper as long as you are publishing that data for the current user.

```
{{from_user.emails.0.address}}
```

Personally I like to use Meteor's collection transforms to extend my models with prototypes that can be used just like template helpers.

```
//first we create our collection and add a transform option
Notifications = new Meteor.Collection("notifications", {
    transform: function(document){
        return new Notification(document);
    }
});

//next we create our constructor
Notification = function(document){
    _(this).extend(document);
};

//Then add some prototypal methods that we can use in our templates.
Notification.prototype = {
    fromUser: function(){
        return Meteor.users.findOne(this.from);
    }
};
```

Now we can use this in our templates like this:

```
{{fromUser.emails.0.address}}
```

We can also take this one really great step farther by using the users `_transform` property to set a function that transforms user documents as well and then add methods to them as well.

```
//transform each user document into a new User instance
Meteor.users._transform = function(document){
    return new User(document);
};

//User constructor
User = function(document){
    _(this).extend(document);
};

//and finally the User prototype with methods
User.prototype = {
    defaultEmail: function(){
        return this.emails && this.emails[0].address;
    }
};
```

Now as a final result you can use it like this:

```
{{#each sent}
    <p>{{fromUser.defaultEmail}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the suggestions, still relatively new to this meteor stuff, very interesting cool stuff. Thanks again!